# OrientDB: Aggregation on edges

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

we are building an application which has a requirement to use GraphDB. We have built the prototype with MySQL but considering usage of graphdb will ease out our efforts. Following is one of the scenarios we have in our application:

A user can make posts to the application. A post can be tagged [upto 3 tags are allowed per post]. Tags has to be a separate node since we need to retrieve the top tags used by a given user.

So we will have 3 nodes: User, Post and Tags. User and Post are connected by an edge [say 'writes' ie User writes Post]. Post and Tags are connected by an edge [say 'has' ie Post has Tags]. And User and Tags are connected by an  edge [Say 'uses' ie User uses Tags].

1. Since a user can write many posts and these posts may share same tags, I want to maintain a count of number of times a tag is used by the user. And I want to maintain that count on the edge 'Uses'. Is this a preferred approach or would you recommend fetching counts using real-time query?
2. I want users to follow posts containing specific tags instead of following users. So is it possible to follow an edge ie maintain follow/unfollow list on the edges ?

I am considering OrientDB for this implementation since Neo4j is expensive.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: We have decided not to use any graphdb at this stage of implementation since they need a good amount of time for learning. We are currently using MySQL. Will update once we decide to go the graph way.